Examples of Lubin-Tate formal groups
I'm currently learning about Lubin-Tate theory: Given a p-adic field $K$ and a uniformizer $\pi \in \mathcal{O}_K$, they consider formal $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules $F$ such that the endomorphism $[\pi]$ of $F$ corresponding to $\pi$ satisfies:
$$
[\pi](T) \equiv \pi T \ \ (\text{mod deg } 2) \qquad \text{and} \qquad  [\pi](T) \equiv T^q \ \ (\text{mod } \pi) 
$$
where $q=|\mathcal{O}_K/\pi|$. These are then used to construct certain totally ramified extensions $L/K$, for which the Norm-residue symbol $(-, L/K)$ can be expressed explicitly in terms of $F$.
Now I was searching (rather unsuccessfully) for concrete examples of this construction. Looking around, I've only found discussions of the "trivial" case $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$. Here one can consider the formal $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module:
\begin{align*}
    F(X,Y) &:= X+Y+XY \\
  [n](T) &:= (1+T)^n - 1 \qquad (\forall n\in \mathbb{Z}_p)
\end{align*}
The corresponding Lubin-Tate extensions are simply the cyclotomic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ by $p^n$-th roots of unity.
Question: Are there any other p-adic fields for which one can write down a Lubin-Tate module that has a similarly simple form?

You could take the formal group law of an elliptic curve with CM, e.g. $y^2 = x^3 - x$.

Thanks for the hint! I'll give that idea a try once I know a bit more about elliptic curves & CM.

The polynomial $T^q+\pi{T}$ can always be used as the polynomial $[\pi](T)$ (Lubin discusses the discovery of this example here). Then $[\pi^n](T)$ is the $n$-fold iterate of $[\pi](T)$, so the Lubin-Tate extension $K_{\pi,n}$ is $K$ adjoined the roots of $[\pi^n](T)$. Note $K_{\pi,1} = K(\sqrt[q-1]{-\pi})$ is a Kummer extension of $K$.
Are you seeking examples where the formal group law itself, not $[\pi](T)$, is a polynomial? That is quite rare.

Not necessarily a polynomial, a power series in closed form would already be great!
Actually, I was mainly hoping for examples where the $u$ can be written out explicitly, since these give the norm residue symbol. But to compute the $u$, you first have to construct the formal group $F$ anyway, right?

@Fungaria no, you don't: for each $a\in\mathcal O_K$, $a$ is the unique power series $aT$ + higher order terms in $\mathcal O_K[[T]]$ such that $\pi=a$: see the bottom paragraph on p. 194 in Lang's Cyclotomic Fields I and II, using $f(T)=g(T)=\pi$. Theorem 1.2 on the top of p. 195 is worth reading too. You need to get used to the idea that the series $u$ don't usually come to you explicitly, but be happy that the two conditions (i) $u = uT$ + higher order terms and (ii) $\pi = u$ are enough to determine $u$.

We don't expect the roots of $\pi^n$ to have explicit descriptions either (esp. when $n \geq 2$).  Does that bother you?

In general? Of course not! But if $\mathbb{Q}p(\zeta{p^n})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ are really the only extensions where the Lubin-Tate construction can be carried out explicitly, then that might bother me a bit. In that case I'd certainly have to reconsider what LT-theory is really trying to achieve. Until now I thought that computing norm residue symbols was at least part of the goal... But that's a completely different question of course!

Let's try unramified extensions: do you understand how the maximal unramified extension $\mathbf Q_p^{\rm nr}$ of $\mathbf Q_p$ has Galois group isomorphic to $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$, and is that explicit to you? Let $K = \mathbf Q_7(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+7x-2$, which is cubic unramified over $\mathbf Q_7$. How do $2$ and $3$ in $\widehat{\mathbf Z}$ permute the roots of $x^3+7x-2$?

You don't need all the coefficients in $u$ to determine how it permutes the roots of $\pi$ with absolute value less than $1$: just knowing enough early coefficients suffices. The roots of $\pi$ with absolute value less than $1$ are finite in number, so write them as $r_1,\ldots,r_q$ and let $d=\min_{i\not= j}|r_i-r_j|>0$. Since $u$ is one of these roots, once we know an $r_j$ such that $|u-r_j| < d$, we get $u=r_j$. To determine $u$ approximately, we only need enough initial coefficients in $u$ since all coefficients are integral and $|r_1|<1$.

Ok, I feel like that's an important point I was missing: To compute the norm residue symbol you only need to know $u$ up to a certain order, which is always possible via the usual recursive procedure. Very reassuring indeed!
Just one last thing I’m curious about: How does your toy example about the cubic unramified extension of $\mathbf{Q}_7$ relate to this? Are you alluding to the fact that, in order to compute how $z \in \widehat{\mathbf Z}$ acts on $\mathbf{Q}_7(\alpha)$, you only need to know it's value mod 3 (i.e. only "approximately")?

My unramified example was partly showing approximate knowledge is enough, but also it complements the LT extensions since LT extns are a carefully chosen tower of totally ramified abelian extensions and the unram. extns. are a "complementary" set of abelian extns whose composite with LT gives the full max. abelian extension.You need to be able to grok the unram. extns very well, not just the LT extensions, in order to access the whole max. abelian extension of a local field.

The isomorphism ${\rm Gal}(L/K) \to K^\times/{\rm N}_{L/K}(L^\times)$ when $L/K$ is finite abelian shows all elements in $K^\times$ only need to known approx. (norm image is open subgroup) to know how they act on a finite abelian extn. of the local field $K$.
